# What is the complete list of events supported by angular's updateOn property of ngModelOptions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

The [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) say

> updateOn: string specifying which event should the input be bound to. You can set several events using an space delimited list. There is a special event called default that matches the default events belonging of the control.

The page mentions a few events: `blur`, `default`, `submit`. Are there any others? Is the full list documented anywhere?

Comment: haven't tested the full list, but I'm pretty sure these correspond to the default HTML Event Attributes;  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know, you can bind any available DOM event to the `updateOn` property. see a full list [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp).

Having a look at the Source of `ngModel`, you can see that the options passed to `updateOn` will get bound to the actual element itself.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L1188

Angular Source:

```
if (modelCtrl.$options.getOption('updateOn')) {
  element.on(modelCtrl.$options.getOption('updateOn'), function(ev) {
    modelCtrl.$$debounceViewValueCommit(ev && ev.type);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> You can now control for a form (or single form elements) when the
>   value or the validity is updated. This feature has been available in
>   AngularJS 1.x but missed in Angular 2+ so far. The following update
>   options can now be used in Angular 5 forms:
>
> **change**: change is the default mode. By using this update option the form / form control is updated after every single change.
>
> **blur**: the blur change mode is only updated the from values / validity status after a form control lost the focus.
>
> **submit**: updates are only done after form submit.

Full source is [here](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-5-forms-update-9587c3735cd3).