# Angular7 - [ngModel] does not update in component, when typing in the same value twice

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, angular-components, angular7, angular-changedetection

#### Minimal Stackblitz Example

**https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqqvz1**

In an Angular 7 App, I have created a simple component with an `<input>` field.

When I change the input-value with the keyboard, I want the value to be formated **onBlur**. - In the minimal example I just want to add the string *" EDIT"* to it.

This is basically working:

- If I type in "test" and blur the field, it will be changed to "test EDIT"
- If I type in "lala" and blur the field, it will be changed to "lala EDIT"

**However**
When I type in "test" - blur (it works) and type in "test" again, it does not work anymore!

The `onInputUpdate()`-function gets called (You can see it in the console log), the variable `inputValue` gets updated (You can see it in the component `{{inputValue}}`), **However the input-value does not change!**
I expect it to be "test EDIT", however it stays "test".

When I type another string it works, however typing in the same string 2 times in a row does not work. Why is that? How can I fix this?

**component.html**

```
{{inputValue}} <br />
<input type="text"
       [ngModel]="inputValue"
       (ngModelChange)="onInputUpdate($event)"
       [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"/>
```

**component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class AppComponent {

  inputValue = "teststring";

  constructor(
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
  ) {}

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.inputValue = "initial";
  }

  public onInputUpdate(inputValue: string) {
    this.inputValue = inputValue + ' EDIT';
    this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
    console.log('onInputUpdate new inputValue', this.inputValue)
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there specific case for the `updateOn` flag away from the default of `change`?

Comment: Try making your own onFocus to reset it?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019330/what-is-the-complete-list-of-events-supported-by-angulars-updateon-property-of

Comment: I only want the value to update **onBlur**, which is why I have set ` [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make sure that the input field is updated after typing the same value again, force the view to update first with the raw text by calling `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges`:

```
public onInputUpdate(inputValue: string) {
  this.inputValue = inputValue;            // Set value to raw input text
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();  // Trigger change detection
  this.inputValue = inputValue + ' EDIT';
  this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qvh21c) for a demo.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly how I want it to behave. Thank you!

Comment: this will work, but anyone know why the two-way binding [(ngModel)] is not updating inputValue value?